# two versions of g++(4.4 and 4.7) exist in centos6.5 ,how to use g++4.7

Tags: c++11, centos6, g++-4.7

I will learn c++11 so I installed g++4.7, when I use `g++ --version`,it shows version of 4.4. But when I use `find / -name g++` ,it shows
`/opt/centos/devtoolset-1.1/root/usr/bin/g++
/usr/bin/g++`
and the first version is 4.7,the second version is 4.4,how to set g++4.7 to deafault. Thanks!

Comment: I have solved it. Use `ln -s /opt/centos/devtoolset-1.1/root/usr/bin/* /usr/local/bin/` and `hash -r`.

Comment: Neither of these compilers actually supports C++11. The first version of gcc in which support is not experimental is `g++ 4.9`.

Comment: Really?Thank you very much!